# Any point in having SSD cache with SSD system disk?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot, cache, hard-drive-cache

Apologize if the title is unclear, had a hard time formulating the question in a sentence.

So I have a Lenovo Y510p which originally came with a 1 TB HDD as system drive and 24 GB SSD cache (M.2 interface if I remember correctly). I've now exchanged the HDD with a 250 GB SSD as my system drive and using the HDD as a secondary storage drive. So the question is:

Is there any point in using the 24 GB SSD as a cache now that the system is running on a SSD itself?

I was thinking of installing ubuntu on the cache drive which I'm booting from a external drive at the moment (which is a bit slow) although I'm not going to ask if that's a good idea since all the threads on here asking that question has been closed for some reason.

Replies appreciated.

Comment: The questions have been closed because, asking if something is a "good idea", leads to answers where people just state an opinion.  It makes no sense, for us as a community, to have answers based on an opinion.  If you want to use the cache drive, for something other then a cache, then you should do so.  The point would be that instead of a 250GB of SSD storage you would have have 250GB on a primary drive and a 24GB secondary drive

Comment: It was not my intent to get others opinions on what I should use my cache drive for, but to get insight into if any complications can arise from using a cache drive as a system drive, and if I would get a decrease in preformance when not using the SSD cache. But I guess the answer is as simple as you say, and I should have formulated my question more preciely.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what are the intended uses for the machine. If it's a main source of entertainment, information and work/hobby use (in other words: my computer is only thing I use to play, watch tv/movies and work) then 250 GB is not enough.

In that case extra 24GB means place for either pagefile only or pagefile + hiberfile. I would give a lot for that extra 24GB right about now.

If it's basic family stuff (email, browsing, photo storage, some text/spreadsheet once a year) - no point bothering with it at all.

NO point using it as cache - the idea behind the setup was to essentially create one hybrid drive out of this SSD cache and normal HDD via Intel Smart Response Technology. No point (counterproductive, in fact) to keep this caching with SSD.

**Source**: hands-on experience of last 6 months. Given chance I would ATT fork out extra to have at least 500GB SSD. And which I may end up doing. Also, I may end up buying this 500GB SSD in m.2 format...

Explanation: I thought I can keep up with 250 GB SSD and USB3.0 external 1TB HDD. Worked up until my daughter figured out that "pulling at this weird black thingy makes funny noise and after that it's perfect teether, while shiny box at the other end is a nice toy to throw around". So at some point you may want to keep everything internally and still have DVD burner to do hard backups of photos, movies and docs, thus HDD in ODD bay is not so great idea (still cool, though). And it simplifies life if you are mobile a lot - more than once I found out that while me and my laptop was *here*, my external HDD was *elsewhere*.